# Создание структуры C++

Tags: c++, struct

Ну очень нужна помощь, я больше не могу, ну не понимаю и всё тут. Хочу циклом заполнять массив из структур. Создаю структуру, в ней два поля. Предположим, что первое поле - это int, а второе - массив char. В функции main сначала надо ввести количество структур в массиве, а потом циклом заполнять его. Моя функция заменяет все поля char на последнее введенное значение. Вот мой код.

```
struct Die {
    int sqrt = 0;
    char* str;
};

int main() {
    char* s = new char[10];
    Die* mas = new Die[10];
    int N;
    int j = 0;
    std::cin >> N;
    for (int i = 0; i < N;i++) {
        std::cin >> s;
        mas[i] = { j, s }; //заполняем структуру, где первое поле - индекс, а второе - строка
        std::cout << mas[i].sqrt << ' ' << mas[i].str << std::endl; //если выводим так, то все нормально
        j += 1;
    }
    std::cout << "_________" << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        std::cout << mas[i].sqrt << ' ' << mas[i].str << std::endl; //а если вот так, то беда
    }
}
```

Вывод

```
3
aaa bbb ccc  
0 aaa 
1 bbb 
2 ccc                                                                                                                   _____________
 
0 ccc 
1 ccc
2 ccc
```

Пожалуйста, помогите...

Comment: А почему бы не использовать `string`? C++ всё таки.

Comment: Зачем вам этот char[10]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну Вы же один раз выделили память под строку, указатели во всех записях указывают на один адрес, и естественно, что там последнее назначенное лежит.

Делайте `mas[i].str = new char[10];` для каждой структуры

Comment: Так тоже не работает, к сожалению.

Comment: Работает.  Возможно, Вы по-прежнему назначаете одну строку полям всех структур. Читайте прямо в поле `std::cin >>mas[i].str;`  или копируйте данные `strcpy`

Comment: Исправил, но выводит совсем не то, что я вводил, а мусор какой-то:(

Comment: Отредактируйте свой пост, добавив в конце новый код

Comment: Я все понял, надо было убрать строку s

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: а вы не подскажете, как теперь память очищать?

Comment: парный к new - delete

Answer (score 0):

у вас получается один указатель на массив букв (строку) для всех элементов массива, поскольку вы передаете в массив лишь указатель на строку

поэтому когда вы выводите содержимое массива уже после ввода всех значений, то вам выводится последний ввод

т.е. если образно - у вас куча народу и вместо того, чтобы каждому дать по коробке вы дали по планшету на который выводится видео из одной коробки и естественно все видят одно и тоже

вам надо каждый раз выделять память под строку и записывать строку

```
for (int i = 0; i < N;i++) {
    char* text= new char[10];
    std::cin >> text;
    mas[i] = { j, text}; //заполняем структуру, где первое поле - индекс, а второе - строка
    std::cout << mas[i].sqrt << ' ' << mas[i].str << std::endl; //если выводим так, то все нормально
    j += 1;
}
```

и вот тогда все будет работать

но лучше всего добавить в вашу структуру конструктор, чтобы наружи не делать лишних выделений памяти, а спрятать это всё вовнутрь структуры, например

```
struct Die {
    int sqrt = 0;
    char* str = nullptr;

    // конструктор
    Die(const int l_sqrt, const char* l_str) {
        sqrt = l_sqrt;
        str = new char[strlen(l_str) + 1];
        strcpy(str, l_str);
    }

    // деструктор
    ~Die() {
        delete [] str;
    }
};
```

и тогда можете использовать так:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N;i++) {
    std::cin >> s;
    mas[i] = Die(j, s); //заполняем структуру, где первое поле - индекс, а второе - строка
    std::cout << mas[i].sqrt << ' ' << mas[i].str << std::endl; //если выводим так, то все нормально
    j += 1;
}
```

Comment: А как в таком случае объявлять массив?

Comment: И куда же будет указывать `mas[i].str` после этой строчки:  `mas[i] = Die(j, s);`?

Comment: @wololo, на строку освобождённую после копирования деструктором временного объекта?

Comment: @vp_arth, угу, свой оператор присваивания добавить в структуру не помешало бы.